# Microphone settings on a Windows PC

Tags: mono, settings, microphone, cmusphinx

What I need is that my audio input from microphone is: Mono 16bit 16000Hz.

I am on a Windows 8.1 PC and i am aware that you can adjust it on the advanced 
settings of microphone.
(Right click on speaker icon in task-bar -> Recording devices -> Properties -> Advanced)

But there is no option for the specific setting i need. An apropriate setting would be tape recorder quality. But i only have CD,DVD and Studioquality.

I found many hints on how to resample a file but i depend on live audio from a microphone. I tried both, internal and external microphones.

I am using a voice recognition program (CMU Sphinx).
It seems that my bad recognition results depend on a incorrectly configured 
microphone.

I already searched for solutions in the Forum of the speech recognition program but my problem seems to depend more general.

Answer (score 0):

Pocketsphinx sets the sample rate for recording itself based on samprate option (default 16000), the issue might be that your driver does not support that rate. In that case you can start pocketsphinx_continuos with other sample rate, for example:

```
       pocketsphinx_continuous -inmic yes -samprate 44100 -nfft 2048
```

In case this does not work you need to share audio dump files. You can collect them by running pocketsphinx with -rawlogdir option:

```
       pocketsphinx_continuous -inmic yes -rawlogdir . -samprate 44100 -nfft 2048
```

Comment: Unfortunately i am using sphinx4-1.0beta6. I use the hellongram sample. The result is not so good. When i switch the language model to  cmusphinx-en-us-5.2.tar.gz which i downloaded from sourceforge, it is even worse.

Comment: beta6 is a very old version. You need to use latest sphinx4 if you want to use java